# d3 - geomaps hover option

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am creating a geographical map of USA using d3 geomaps.
I want a state to be highlighted when I hover over the state. Is that possible? 
Here's my current code:

```
<html>
            <head>
     <meta    charset="utf-8">
    <link href="d3-geomap/css/d3.geomap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="d3-geomap/vendor/d3.geomap.dependencies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="d3-geomap/js/d3.geomap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
 var map = d3.geomap.choropleth()
.geofile('d3-geomap/topojson/countries/USA.json')
.projection(d3.geo.albersUsa)
.column('2012')
.unitId('fips')
.scale(1000)
.legend(true);

d3.csv('data.csv', function(error, data) {
d3.select('#map')
    .datum(data)
    .call(map.draw, map);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, check out this JSFiddle I've made : http://jsfiddle.net/b6huwcd7/1/

All i've done is adding this CSS code to the example code :

```
path.unit:hover{
    fill:red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps a lot!

Comment: No problem, but I don't see why you had to post another answer with the same answer as I gave, also, if my answer answered your question you can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

based on @black0ut 's response, here's the answer:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta    charset="utf-8">
    <link href="d3-geomap/css/d3.geomap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="d3-geomap/vendor/d3.geomap.dependencies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="d3-geomap/js/d3.geomap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style>
    path.unit:hover{
    fill:red;
}
</style>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
    </html>

     <script>
     var map = d3.geomap.choropleth()
    .geofile('d3-geomap/topojson/countries/USA.json')
    .projection(d3.geo.albersUsa)
    .column('2012')
    .unitId('fips')
    .scale(1000)
    .legend(true);

    d3.csv('data.csv', function(error, data) {
    d3.select('#map')
        .datum(data)
        .call(map.draw, map);
    });

    </script>
```